# TypeError when passing a list (Python)

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Code:

```
import itertools
import string
import hashlib

def hash_f(x):
    h = hashlib.md5(x)
    return int(h.hexdigest(),base=16)


value = raw_input("Enter a value: ")
oneChar = [map(''.join, itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=1))]
twoChar = [map(''.join, itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=2))]
threeChar = [map(''.join, itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=3))]
possibleValues = oneChar + twoChar + threeChar

hashed_list = [int(hashlib.md5(x).hexdigest(), base=16) for x in possibleValues]

for x in hashed_list:
    if hash_f(value) == x:
        print "MATCH"
```

The error I get when I try to run this code is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "hash.py", line 18, in <module>
        hashed_list = [int(hashlib.md5(x).hexdigest(), base=16) for x in possibleValues]
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not list
```

Going through this in my head, the only problem that I can see is an error with hashlib, but shouldn't that be negated due to the fact that I'm cycling through each individual value in possibleValues?

All help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of map is a list already, did you mean to use:

```
oneChar = map(''.join, itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=1))
twoChar = map(''.join, itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=2))
threeChar = map(''.join, itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The possibleValues is a list of lists. Remove the `[]` around the map calls in order to get one list of strings:

```
oneChar = map(''.join, itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=1))
twoChar = map(''.join, itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=2))
threeChar = map(''.join, itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=3))
```